# How can I fill different colors for circles on Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, save, restore

I have two circles that same color, and I am trying to figure out find a way to have different color circles on the canvas. I am wondering if I can use the CanvasRenderingContext2D.save() and CanvasRenderingContext2D.restore()
method to create a different color. If the methods work, how can I attempt this?

Edit: I was able to color the circles in different colors after I tried

1. beginPath, 2. draw 3. closePath 4. set color 5. stroke/fill. Do that for both circles:

that Chris G suggested.

enter code here

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasGame");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var model = {
  circle1: { x: 300, y: 200},
  circle2: { x: 200, y: 200 }
};

var radius = 50;

function view(ctx, model) {
  function circle(c) {
   ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.save();

  ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true); 
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
 
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true); 
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
 }

 // clear canvas
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

 circle(model.circle1);
 circle(model.circle2);
}

function redraw() {
  view(ctx, model);
}

redraw();

function getCircleForPosition(x, y) {
  function intersect(a, b) {
    var d2 = Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2) + Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2);
    r2 = Math.pow(radius, 2);
    return d2 < r2;
  }

  return [model.circle1, model.circle2].find(circle => intersect(circle, { x, y }));
}


canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  model.dragging = getCircleForPosition(e.pageX, e.pageY);
}, 0);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  model.dragging = undefined;
}, 0);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (model.dragging) {
    model.dragging.x = e.pageX;
    model.dragging.y = e.pageY;
    redraw();
  }
}, 0);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Canvas</title>
   
</head>
<body>
        <canvas id="canvasGame" style='background-color:#EEE;' width='600px' height='500px'>
            
        </canvas>
        <div>
  

    <script src="JS/object.js"></script>
        
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, all you need to do is change `ctx.strokeStyle` in between the two `ctx.stroke()` calls.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed the ctx.stroke() to ctx.strokeStyle = "pink"; but nothing change.

Comment: You need to 1. beginPath, 2. draw 3. closePath 4. set color 5. stroke/fill. Do that for both circles: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/pvtesy68/

Comment: @Kaiido true, updated fiddle

Comment: Thank you!!!!! Finally got it :)